# Meteor publication and subscription not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, publish, subscription

I am working on an admin page that shows a list of the user's `orders`. For some reason, publication function is not receiving the user's ID as a parameter from my subscription function.

My `user` object contains the attributes:

```
_id
userId
confirmed
```

My `orders` object contains the attributes:

```
_id
userId
amount
date
```

My publication:

```
Meteor.publish('clientOrders', function(userId) {
    console.log('user is ' + userId);
    return Order.find({_id: userId});
});
```

My subscription:

```
viewClientOrders = RouteController.extend({
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    waitOn: function () { 
    Meteor.subscribe('clientOrders', this.params._id);
},
action: function() {
    this.render('viewClientOrders');
}

});
```

My route:

```
Router.route('/viewClientOrders/:id', {name: 'viewClientOrders', controller: 'viewClientOrders', onBeforeAction: requireLogin});
```

I did a console.log for the userId and it returns null, although I clearly passed a userId parameter (`this.params._id`) in my subscription function. However, if I pass a parameter of 3, for testing purposes, it will work. Also, I used a similar publication/subscription method to view a client's profile, passing in the exact same parameters and it works fine...

Anyone know what's going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you `return` in your `waitOn`. Iron Router will only proceed to render if it knows the subscription is ready:

```
viewClientOrders = RouteController.extend({
    waitOn: function () { 
        return Meteor.subscribe('clientOrders', this.params._id);
    }
    ...
```

Make sure you've also set a `loadingTemplate` ([docs](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#the-waiton-option)).

Comment: Thanks - the `return` is a great catch. I added it but the data still isn't loading. Furthermore, i'm still getting a `null` in my console for `console.log('user is ' + userId)`... which means the userId isn't being passed from the subscription into the publication for some reason...

Comment: @user1547174 Your route looks like `/order/:_id`, i hope? You've not mentioned this. Also check you use a `loadingTemplate`. The url you visit should be something like `/order/434fisdfsd`. I hope you don't mean you want the `userId` as in the `_id` of logged in user (which is `this.userId`) and not the `_id` in the route's URL.

Comment: i updated my question to show my route & loading template. also, the userId is not the _id of the logged in user. The userId belongs to the user's profile that the admin wants to see. That's why each order has a userId attribute to match it to a user's _id attribute.

Comment: nevermind, i found the issue... i was missing hte under score in my route (initially it was `/:id` instead of `/:_id`. Thanks for your help!